# PowerShell failing to convert JSON to CSV

Tags: json, powershell

I have spent a bit of time researching how to convert Json to a CSV file using powershell but am failing to have it complete properly. Below is the syntax I have created:

```
$pathToOutputFile = "C:\OrderLinQ\TESTING\IN\CatalogsRetrieved\test.txt"
$pathToJsonFile = "C:\OrderLinQ\TESTING\IN\CatalogsRetrieved\test.json"
Get-Content -Path $pathToJsonFile |
    ConvertFrom-Json |
    ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation |
    Set-Content $pathToOutputFile
```

However, when I attempt to execute this, I get an argument exception error:

```
ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid array passed in, ']' expected. (1): [
At line:1 char:69
+ Get-Content "C:\OrderLinQ\TESTING\IN\CatalogsRetrieved\test.json" | ConvertFrom- ...
+                                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand
```

[image]

Any thoughts as to what I'm doing wrong? I've verified my file using JSONLint and it shows verified. Example file can be found at https://api.myjson.com/bins/mo59w. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try using `-Raw` on `Get-Content`

Comment: according to `get-help ConvertFrom-Json -examples` you can also (Get-Content JsonFile.JSON) -join "`n" | ConvertFrom-Json.

Comment: `Get-Content | ConvertFrom-Json` works without `-join`ing lines, in my tests. The error message says there's a json parsing problem with the input. @TheIncorrigible1 is probably right; maybe `Get-Content` needs a correct `-Encoding` parameter for your input file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I've also attached the output

```
$pathToOutputFile = "D:\output.csv"
$pathToJsonFile = "D:\test.json"
$json = Get-Content -Path $pathToJsonFile

    function ConvertFrom-JsonToCsv {
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        $json        
    )

    Process {
        ($json | ConvertFrom-Json) | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
    }
}

ConvertFrom-JsonToCsv $json | Set-Content $pathToOutputFile
```

## Output[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping me with this HariHaran. I tried this and still encounter the same error on a different line - 


ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid array passed in, ']' expected. (1): [
At line:12 char:18
+         ($json | ConvertFrom-Json) | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand

Comment: The problem appears to be the last line of code. Everything before that runs correctly.

Comment: I have used the same sample that you've provided me and it went fine. As you can see the expected output. Are you adding more content to the file again ? an another array ?